# Can a direct path insert into a LOB column?

Tags: oracle, direct-path

If my target table has a BLOB column in it, can I use direct path?  I found this statement from Oracle:

- Supplemental logging is not enabled and the table does not have a LOB column

I did not know if this was a statement with both conditions that need to be met at the same time or they just didn't put this on two sentences.

Is the AND for both options?

or does it mean:

- Supplemental logging is not enabled
- the table does not have a LOB
  column

Comment: Could you point to where you saw that "statement from Oracle"?